# How do I re-create a built-in view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I duplicated a view before making changes, but it didn't save and I'd changed most of the view settings before I realised I was working on the original.

How can I recreate the standard taxonomy view?

I am using Drupal 9, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Export your current config using `drush cex -y`
- Copy/paste the `/web/core/modules/taxonomy/config/optional/views.view.taxonomy_term.yml` into your config directory (usually `/config`)
- Import the config using `drush cim -y`

Comment: Absolutely wonderful, thank you!